# como puedo mostrar una tabla con php y mysql

Tags: base-de-datos

Quiero mostrar un tabla pero al momento de mostrarla me enredo
necesito ayuda para poder mostrarla ya me puedo conectar pero no importarla

este es el código para conectarme:

```html
<?php
 function conectarse (){
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*********") or die("No se pudo conectar: " . mysql_error());
  if (!$link) {
   echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
   echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
   echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
   exit;
  }
  
  
  if(!mysqli_select_db($link,"precioproductos")){
   echo "Error: No se pudo conectar con la base de datos." . PHP_EOL;
   exit;
  }
  return $link; 

 }
 
  

?>
```

Comment: Debes ser mas especifico, lo que quieres es mostrar los datos de la tabla? si es asi solo debes hacer una consulta a la BD y lo que te retorne recogerlo en un array y ese array recorrerlo como quieres que se miuestre.

Comment: si eso es lo que quiero hacer pero el problema es que no se como y ademas lo he intentado pero no me muestra nada solo errores que no se como se corrigen .Creo que todos los videos que he visto están desactualizado por que ponen mysql y e visto paguinas que ponen mysqli y ninguno hace lo que se supone que deberian de hacer

Answer (score 2):

Crea un archivo .php y pega el siguiente código, reemplaza por los valores de tu conexión y los datos que devuelve tu query.

```html
<html>

<body>
    <?php/* Abrimos la base de datos */
   $conx = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
   if (!$conx) die ("Error al abrir la base <br/>". mysql_error()); 
   mysql_select_db("test") OR die("Connection Error to Database");    

   /* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
   $sql="select * from usuario";
   $result= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");

   /* Desplegamos cada uno de los registros dentro de una tabla */  
 echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>";

 /*Primero los encabezados*/
  echo "<tr>
          <th colspan=5> Agenda personal </th>
        <tr>
         <th> ID </th><th> Nombre </th><th> Apellido </th> <th> Teléfono </th><th> Email </th>
      </tr>";


      /*Y ahora todos los registros */

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr>
         <td align='right'> $row[id] </td>
         <td> $row[nombre] </td>
         <td> $row[apellido] </td>
         <td> $row[telefono] </td>
         <td> $row[email] </td>
      </tr>";}

      echo "</table>";
 ?>
</body>

</html>
```